# any open source library for business process modeling notation?

Tags: java, open-source

Is their any open source library that i can use for  business process modeling notation allowing user to create diagrams,store them and retrieve when needed.

Comment: http://www.jboss.org/jbpm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Activiti](http://activiti.org/) and [Bonita](http://www.bonitasoft.org) has their own modelers and also provides engine, if you want only diagrams [dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/??) and [yaoqiang](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bpmn/) are great alternatives.